# How different between doctrine:generate and generate:doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using the `Doctrine2` to manage my database. 
When I listed all the Doctrine2 commands, I wonder why there are two types of commands which are the same explanation:

```
generate:doctrine:crud                Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
generate:doctrine:entities            Generates entity classes and method stubs from yourmapping information
generate:doctrine:entity              Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle
generate:doctrine:form                Generates a form type class based on a Doctrine entity
```

and

```
doctrine:generate:crud                Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
doctrine:generate:entities            Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information
doctrine:generate:entity              Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle
doctrine:generate:form                Generates a form type class based on a Doctrine entity
```

Are there any different between the two groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands do the same thing:

generate:doctrine:xxx commands

are the alias of :

doctrine:generate:xxx commands

They achieve the same goal and can be used interchangeably .

If you look at the source code of the the two command you will found out more:

- doctrine:generate:entities: ( from the Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle )

  ```
     $this
      ->setName('doctrine:generate:entities')
      ->setAliases(array('generate:doctrine:entities'))
      ->setDescription('Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information')
      ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'A bundle name, a namespace, or a class name')
      ->addOption('path', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The path where to generate entities when it cannot be guessed')
      ->addOption('no-backup', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Do not backup existing entities files.')
  ```
- doctrine:generate:entity  ( from the Sensio\Bundle\Generator bundle )

  ```
      $this
      ->setName('doctrine:generate:entity')
      ->setAliases(array('generate:doctrine:entity'))
      ->setDescription('Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle')
      ->addOption('entity', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The entity class name to initialize (shortcut notation)')
      ->addOption('fields', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The fields to create with the new entity')
      ->addOption('format', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'Use the format for configuration files (php, xml, yml, or annotation)', 'annotation')
      ->addOption('with-repository', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Whether to generate the entity repository or not')
  ```

It looks like the two bundles above completes each other. i.e. there is no doctrine:generate:entity command in DoctrineBundle and there's no doctrine:generate:entities in the Generator bundle but they together give you the full list of related commands. There's no reinventing of the wheel.

Comment: From the given example, you gave `doctrine:generate:entities` and `doctrine:generate:entity` but How different between `doctrine:generate:entities` and `generate:doctrine:entities`?

Comment: No different. it looks like the two bundles above complete each other. i.e. there is no doctrine:generate:entity command in DoctrineBundle and there's no doctrine:generate:entities in the Generator bundle